# Error message after incorrect input in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to add validation to input data in django admin, so I've added such code to my `models.py`

```
class Score(models.Model):
  #fields description
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        if (validating data):
            super(Score, self).save(*args, **kw)
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Error input")
```

I can't understand what I have to write in `ValidationError` to see this message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this in the [proper place](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects), instead of in `save`

> To assign exceptions to a specific field, instantiate the
>   ValidationError with a dictionary, where the keys are the field names.
>   We could update the previous example to assign the error to the
>   pub_date field:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        # Don't allow draft entries to have a pub_date.
        if self.status == 'draft' and self.pub_date is not None:
            raise ValidationError({'pub_date': 'Draft entries may not have a publication date.'})
        ...
```